# Doubt regarding Chomsky hierarchy

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

I know that intersection of CFL and regular language is CFL and hence CFL is closed if one of the languages is regular. One of the most common examples to show this is regular language being $p^*q^*$ and CFL being $p^n q^n$.

Now if I promote regular language to CFL according to Chomsky hierarchy as all regular languages are context free languages, then the question changes to CFL intersection CFL which is not closed and hence we cannot say that the resultant language is surely a "CFL".

Why are the results different using both the methods?

Comment: When we say that "intersection of two CFLs is not necessarily a CFL" we mean "any two CFLs". When we talk about Regular languages we mean a special subclass of CFLs. You can rephrase it as "intersection of any CFL and a CFL from a special subsclass (Regular languages) is CFL".

Comment: So can't I promote regular language directly to CFL and apply the rules ? You said "intersection of two CFLs is not necessarily CFL "  and it is true for "any two CFLs" . So here both are CFLs when I promote right?

Comment: You can treat Regular languages as CFLs, for example when you prove something, but you can not generalize results to all CFLs (to the whole class of CFLs). More abstractly, any result obtained for some set does not have to be valid for a superset containing that set. Here we are talking about a special subset of CFLs - Regular languages.

Comment: Something like this. You have two sets $N$ (all natural numbers) and $E$ (all natural even numbers). It is true that if $a \in N$ and $b \in E$ then $ab$ is always an even number. However, you cannot say that for the set $N$ and any set $A$, in particular if $A$ is a set of odd natural numbers.

Comment: Just one more doubt. If we have to determine what is the class is complement of CFL, then we promote the language to CSL and CSL is closed under complement , so we say that complement of CFL is CSL. Here why do we promote the language?

Comment: Actually, you don't have to "promote the language" every time you want to prove something. Complement of CFL may be CSL, or even again a CFL. For example complement of an empty set is $\Sigma^*$ which is a CFL even a Regular language.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Context-free languages are closed under intersection with regular languages, but not under intersection with context-free languages. This doesn't mean that the intersection of any two context-free languages is necessarily not context-free. Rather, it means quite the opposite – that the intersection of two context-free languages is not necessarily context-free.

Comment: If all you know about two languages is that they are context-free, then you cannot conclude anything about the context-freeness of their intersection. If you know that one of them is moreover regular, then you can conclude that the intersection is context-free. In general, when you know more information, you can conclude more.

Comment: "I know that intersection of CFL and regular language is CFL and hence CFL is closed if one of the languages is regular. " -- you need to be more precise about when you are talking about the two classes, and when about elements from the classes.